# Cursor with a where clause

Tags: sql, oracle, where-clause

I am trying to use a cursor with a where clause. It shouldnt be much different from the simple cursor I assume. I tried the following in my case but doesnt seem to print any output.

```
    Declare 
      BG_TOTAL number;
     SDO_GEOM varchar2 ;

      cursor c1 is 
        select 
        SDO_GEOM.SDO_AREA(GEOMETRY, 0.005,'unit = SQ_MILE') 
          from <tablename>
          where SITE_ID= 8;

      Type SITE_TAB_TYPE is table of  c1%ROWTYPE;

      SITE_LIST SITE_TAB_TYPE;

    Begin
      open c1;
      FETCH c1 BULK COLLECT INTO SITE_LIST;

      close c1;


         DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE(SITE_LIST(1).SDO_GEOM);

    Exception
        When others then 
        DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE(sqlerrm);
    End;



[Error] Execution (3: 11): ORA-06550: line 3, column 11:
PLS-00215: String length constraints must be in range (1 .. 32767)
ORA-06550: line 7, column 5:
PLS-00487: Invalid reference to variable 'SDO_GEOM'
ORA-06550: line 7, column 5:
PLS-00487: Invalid reference to variable 'SDO_GEOM'
ORA-06550: line 22, column 40:
PLS-00302: component 'SDO_GEOM' must be declared
ORA-06550: line 22, column 6:
PL/SQL: Statement ignored
```

Comment: What actual **database** are you using? SQL is just the query language .... please update your tags accordingly!

Comment: Any error message? What does <tablename> mean?

Comment: the table name on which it will perform the select query . I have just put that tag to replace with the tablename.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is that you are trying to output the whole table object to standard output, whereas you should iterate through it. Instead of:

```
DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE(SITE_LIST.SDO_GEOM);
```

Use something like this:

```
FOR v_i IN 1..SITE_LIST.LAST
LOOP
  dbms_output.put_line(SITE_LIST(v_i).SOME_COLUMN_NAME);
END LOOP;
```

Replace the `SOME_COLUMN_NAME` with a name of a column selected in your cursor.

**Edit**

You have to provide an index of the element of your collection to which you want to refer to:

```
dbms_output.put_line(site_list(1).SDO_GEOM);
```

**Edit #2**

Yes.. you didn't specify column alias for value selected in your query. Try this cursor instead:

```
cursor c1 is 
        select 
        SDO_GEOM.SDO_AREA(GEOMETRY, 0.005,'unit = SQ_MILE') AS my_value
          from <tablename>
          where SITE_ID= 8;
```

And then:

```
dbms_output.put_line(site_list(1).my_value);
```

Comment: I dont want to loop through as of now. I just want to print the area of the selected id.

Comment: @Nathan Then you should use: `site_list(1).SDO_GEOM`.

Comment: @Nathan You have to specify alias for your column - check my answert, edit#2.

Comment: My bad I just .I didnt use the term "as" and then removed it

Comment: This is has been fixed. Thank You.

Comment: @Nathan You have to specify length of a variable. `SDO_GEOM varchar2` is wrong, should be for example `SDO_GEOM varchar2(2000)`. Next, is `SDO_GEOM` a package? Does it work when you supply the size of `VARCHAR2` variable that I've mentioned?

Comment: I didnt specify the length for SDO_GEOM at all.